# R: dplyr arrange by row number

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to order a dataset according to values in columns in ascending order.

I have a dataset with 1 row and 3000+ columns. I guess I can just change it to a list and use `.[[n]]` but I was thinking if there was another way.

data looks something like this only with more columns and values.

`structure(list(a = -0.00106163456888295, b = -4.11357273721094e-05, 
    c = -0.000181424293930435), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")`

I expect something like this:

`b                       c                    a
1 -4.1135727372109401e-05 -0.00018142429393043499 -0.00106163456888295`

I understand you can arrange by column number by doing the following:

`.[[column number]]`

for example:
`mtcars %>% arrange(.[[2]])`

what is the row number equivalent?

Comment: reproducible example: 


mtcars %>% arrange(.[[2]])

Comment: charlie090, perhaps I'm confused ... if you type in `mydata`, it is already ordered by row-number. What are you intending to do?

Comment: @r2evans, sorry for the confusion.
I have a dataset with 1 row and 3000+ columns. I guess I can just change it to a list and use `.[[n]]` but I was thinking if there was another way.

data looks something like this only with more columns and values.
`structure(list(a = -0.00106163456888295, b = -4.11357273721094e-05, 
    c = -0.000181424293930435), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")`

Comment: @akrun I checked your arrange_at(n) solution but it doesnt seem to order the values in the columns

Comment: @akrun I have updated the text with an expected

Comment: charlie090, if one of the answers addresses your question, please accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to order the columns based on the values in the single row.

```r
z <- structure(list(a = -0.00106163456888295, b = -4.11357273721094e-05, 
    c = -0.000181424293930435), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

Base R:

```r
z[,order(z[1,])]
#                a               c                b
# 1 -0.00106163457 -0.000181424294 -0.0000411357274
```

Tidyverse:

```r
library(dplyr)
z %>%
  select_at(order(.))
```

Note: I think your expected output might not be correct, as the values are not ordered. Your intended output:

```r
c(-0.000181424293930435,       -0.00106163456888295,    -4.11357273721094e-05)
# [1] -0.0001814242939 -0.0010616345689 -0.0000411357274
diff(c(-0.000181424293930435,       -0.00106163456888295,    -4.11357273721094e-05))
# [1] -0.000880210275  0.001020498842
```

shows the first value is *greater than* the second, but the second is *less than* the third. If they were ordered, I would expect the `diff` to be always-nonnegative; if reverse-ordered, `diff` should be always-nonpositive.

Comment: ah yes sorry my expected should be in the order of b c a....I used z[,order(-z[1,])]

Answer (score 0):

We can `unlist` the first row, `order` and use that in `select`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   select(order(-unlist(.[1,])))
#             b             c            a
#1 -4.113573e-05 -0.0001814243 -0.001061635
```

It can be also used a general solution i.e if we want to do this based on a particular row

```
n <- 3
mtcars %>% 
    select(order(-unlist(.[n,])))
```

---

Or reshape to 'long' and then use `arrange`, get the column names and then `select`

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
   arrange(desc(value)) %>% 
   pull(name) %>% 
   select(df1, .)
#              b             c            a
#1 -4.113573e-05 -0.0001814243 -0.001061635
```

---

Or `enframe`, then do a `arrange`, `pull` the 'name' column and use that in `select`

```
library(tibble)
as.list(df1) %>% 
     enframe %>%
     unnest(c(value)) %>%
     arrange(desc(value)) %>% 
     pull(name) %>% 
     select(df1, .)
```

Or if we want to select the column 'c'

```
df1 %>%
    select(c, everything())
#             c            a             b
#1 -0.0001814243 -0.001061635 -4.113573e-05
```

---

In `base R`, we can do

```
 df1[order(-unlist(df1[1,]))]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = -0.00106163456888295, b = -4.11357273721094e-05, 
c = -0.000181424293930435), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```